# remplazar valor de object en angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Hola necesito usar el `id` que mando desde la vista, el código del switch es este:

```
       <div ng-repeat="model in modelo_final">
         <div style="float:left; padding-right:100px;">
         <div class="can-toggle demo-rebrand-2">
         <input  id={{model.id}} type="checkbox" ng-model="idrecibo[model.id]" ng-change="changeItem()">
          <label for={{model.id}}>
           <div class="can-toggle__switch" data-checked="Yes" data-unchecked="No"></div>
           <div class="can-toggle__label-text"><p style="font-size:15px; width:100px;">{{model.nombre}}</p></div>
           </label>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
```

lo cual al ser dinámico le mando `model.id` que corresponde a su `id` respectivo, este lo quiero usar en el controlador para poder activar y desactivar el switch  `$scope.idrecibo = {};`

Al apretar el switch (activar) manda su `id`. por consola, y se vería algo como esto:

[image: image1]

Y si activo otro botón:

[image: lolo]

lo cual me gustaría que se remplazase, así siempre tener uno (el ultimo que active) y ese poder usarlo para decirle a mi web services que active el modulo o desactive.

y otra pregunta, como puedo sacar el *true false* de ahi? cosa que me quede solo el numero o como debería usarlo para enviar solo el numero?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`idRecibo` es un arreglo que por index tiene el id del modulo y por valor `true` o `false` dependiendo del switch simplemente para obtener el valor que envias cuando cambia el switch es :

```
ng-change="changeItem(model.id)"
```

Esta funcion debe recibir como parametro el dato `model.id`

```
$scope.changeItem = function(id_model){
     console.log($scope.idrecibo[id_model]);
}
```

Eso te entregara el valor `true` o `false` del switch que cambiaste y no todos.

Al web service debes enviarle por parametro siempre el `$scope.idrecibo[id_model]`

Comment: agregue tu código entre mi controlador y me sale undefined

Comment: @HernanHumaña que variable imprimes en la imagen que pusiste?

Comment: console.log($scope.idrecibo); y esté también está definido con []

Comment: Entonces ahi debes imprimir $scope.idrecibo[modulo_id]

Comment: sale solo true or false, según selección, el modulo_id a que hace referencia? .

Comment: Edite @HernanHumaña

Comment: Si, eso sale eso es lo que necesitas para enviar al webservice, tienes el modulo id que entra por parametro y su valor